# $2n$th derivative of $(x^2-1)^n$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, special-functions, implicit-differentiation, legendre-polynomials

How is the derivative $\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}(x^2-1)^n=(2n)!$. I have tried to use Leibniz's formula but couldn't reach the solution.

Comment: It is not. It is $(2n)!$.

Comment: ohh. sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: Try another edit. That is not $(2n)!$. To help with your question though, $(x^2-1)^n=x^{2n}+P(x)$ where $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less than $2n$. Therefore $\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}(x^2-1)^n=\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}x^{2n}$. I'll leave it to you from there.

Comment: By the binomial theorem,

$$(x^2-1)^n=(x^2)^n-n(x^2)^{n-1}+\frac{n(n-1)}2(x^2)^{n-2}-\cdots (-1)^n.$$

Answer (score 5):

The leading term of the polynomial is $x^{2n},$ so
\begin{align}
p'(x) &= 2nx^{2n-1}+\ldots,\\
p''(x) &= 2n(2n-1)x^{2n-2}+\ldots,\\
p'''(x) &= 2n(2n-1)(2n-2)x^{2n-3}+\ldots,\\
\ldots\\
p^{(2n-1)}(x) &= 2n(2n-1)(2n-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot3\cdot2x\\
p^{(2n)}(x) &= 2n(2n-1)(2n-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1
\end{align}
while the other terms disappear along the calculation.

Answer (score 5):

*Hint*: you can show with induction that the $n$th derivative of a polynomial of $n$ degree is $a_n \cdot (n)!$

Answer (score 2):

$$(x^{2}-1)^{n} = x^{2n}-{{n}\choose{1}} x^{2n-2} + {{n}\choose{2}} x^{2n-4} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + (-1)^{n} $$
$$\frac{d^{2n}}{(dx)^{2n}} x^{2n} = (2n)! $$ ,,, because for others term, derivative is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to write $ \ f(x) \ = \ (x^2 - 1)^n \ = \ \underbrace{(x + 1)^n}_{g(x)}·\underbrace{(x - 1)^n}_{h(x)} \ \ , $  for which we have $ \ g^{(n)}(x) \ = \ h^{(n)}(x) \ = \ n! \ $ and $ \ g^{(k)}(x) \ = \ h^{(k)}(x) \ = \ 0 \ \ , $ for $ \ k \ > \ n \ \ . $  The "general Leibniz rule" then gives us
$$ f^{(2n)}  \ \ = \ \ \binom{2n}{0}·g^{(2n)}·h \ + \ \binom{2n}{1}·g^{(2n-1)}·h' \ + \ \binom{2n}{2}·g^{(2n-2)}·h'' $$
$$ + \ \ldots \ + \ \binom{2n}{n - 1}·g^{(n+1)}·h^{(n-1)} \ + \ \binom{2n}{n}·g^{(n)}·h^{(n)} \ + \ \binom{2n}{n + 1}·g^{(n-1)}·h^{(n+1)}   $$
$$ + \ \ldots \ + \ \binom{2n}{2n - 2}·g''·h^{(2n-2)} \ + \ \binom{2n}{2n - 1}·g'·h^{(2n-1)} \ + \ \binom{2n}{2n}·g·h^{(2n)} \ \ .  $$

Every product term in this "binomial" expansion is then equal to zero, *except* for the central one, which is
$$ \binom{2n}{n} \ · \ g^{(n)}(x) \ · \ h^{(n)}(x) \ \ = \ \ \frac{(2n)!}{n! \ · \ n!} \ · \ n! \ · \ n! \ \ .    $$
Hence,  $ \ f^{(2n)}(x)  \ \ = \ \ (2n)! \ \ . $